# Meteor Accounts with MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm fairly new to Meteor and currently have an application using MongoDB as the database. But there may be a possibility that I have to switch to MySQL due to server requirements.

Has anyone tried to use MySQL as their database of choice with a MeteorJS Application? I understand their are packages available to make this possible such as meteor-mysql and numtel:mysql, but I'm just looking for some feedback with tools like these. I'm also interested to find out how this work with regards to Accounts/Meteor.users etc as I understand these work with a Mongo User Collection?

Any feedback or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to use databases other than mongo with Meteor.

However, your question sounds more like that you are asking whether Mongo can be entirely disposed with mysql. Maybe, but in my experience, don't count on having majority of packages working out of the box. That includes builtin Accounts package. That means a lot of plumbing and debugging which might defeat the purpose of using Meteor.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, totally agree. I wonder if this kind of thing will be supported out of the box in the near future.

Comment: Can't say I know. Have a look at their relevant card and +1 it https://trello.com/c/Gf6YxFp2/42-sql-support

Answer (score 0):

Check this meteor package [nodets:mysql](https://atmospherejs.com/nodets/mysql) 
.This package provides an easy (but advanced) use of Mongo.Collection code-style but for Mysql Databases.

I 'm updating this package almost every day with new features, I am thinking to add Meteor.createUser functionality for mysql too.

Comment: Is this package active, As the github link points to page not found page